# Using resources as parameters of Attributes

Tags: c#

there is a way to use Static resources as Argumentos for properties ?

imagine this

```
[IsSecured("Secured","Here must be a description of the class")]
public class Secured
{
}
```

I need the second argumento to be an static resource. Something like this

```
[IsSecured("Secured",ClassNames.SecuredClassNameDescription)]
public class Secured
{
    [Allowed("Secured",ClassNames.SecuredMymethodDescription)]
    public string Mymethod()
    {
    } 
}
```

**ClassNames** is a **.resx** file tha contain a `SecuredClassNameDescription` and `SecuredMymethodDescription` text resources

Answer (score 1):

Those are *attributes*, not properties.
Attribute parameters must be compile-time constants.

However, you can make your own inherited attribute which takes a resource *name* in the constructor (losing type safety) and passes the resource value to the base constructor:

```
public sealed class AllowedByResourceAttribute : AllowedAttribute {
    public AllowedByResourceAttribute(string name, string resourceName) : base(name, GetResource(resourceName)) { }
}
```

Comment: Tks, but do you have some sample ?